# Unity: calibrating an Android gyroscope controlled tilt platform

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

so I am trying to make a platform tilt with gyroscope controls. When I load the game the platform is already tilted as my program seems to create a constant torque based on my phone's physical location relative to the y axis. I need to be able to set my phones returned location to (0,0,0) or create a torque that can oppose the constant movement of the phone so that these controls are more manageable. Any ideas?

```
public class balance : MonoBehaviour {
    public float torque;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate() {
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        rb.transform.Rotate(Input.gyro.attitude.x, 0, Input.gyro.attitude.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rotate only by the delta of the rotation from the last frame and this frame (of FixedUpdate). like this:

```
public class balance : MonoBehaviour {
     public float torque;
     public Rigidbody rb;
     private Vector3 prefFrameRotation;
     private Vector3 deltaRotation;

     void Start() {
         Input.gyro.enabled = true;
         deltaRotation = Vector3.zero;
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
     }
     void FixedUpdate() 
         deltaRotation = prefFrameRotation - Input.gyro.attitude;
         //you don't even need to use Time.fixedDeltaTime because
         //the calculations are per fixedUpdate anyways
         rb.transform.Rotate(deltaRotation.x, 0, deltaRotation.z);
         prefFrameRotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
     }
}
```